# How to crate va_list in kotlin native

Tags: android, java-native-interface, kotlin-native

When I use kotlin native to build android so, and I want to create Bitmap object in native, I do it by reflection :

```
val bitmapClass = env.pointed.pointed?.FindClass?.invoke(env, "android/graphics/Bitmap".cstr.ptr)
val creatBitmapFunction = env.pointed.pointed?.GetStaticMethodID?.invoke(env, bitmapClass, "createBitmap".cstr.ptr, "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap\$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;".cstr.ptr)
val configName = env.pointed.pointed?.NewStringUTF?.invoke(env, "ARGB_8888".cstr.ptr)
val bitmapConfigClass = env.pointed.pointed?.FindClass?.invoke(env, "android/graphics/Bitmap\$Config".cstr.ptr)
....
```

but when I call `Bitmap.createBitmap` to create object,

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(@NonNull @ColorInt int[] colors,
            int width, int height, Config config)
```

I have to call "CallStaticObjectMethodV" :

```
public final var CallStaticObjectMethodV: kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<kotlinx.cinterop.CFunction<(kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<platform.android.JNIEnvVar /* = kotlinx.cinterop.CPointerVarOf<platform.android.JNIEnv /* = kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<platform.android.JNINativeInterface> */> */>?, platform.android.jclass? /* = kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<out kotlinx.cinterop.CPointed>? */, platform.android.jmethodID? /* = kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<cnames.structs._jmethodID>? */, kotlinx.cinterop.CValue<platform.posix.va_list /* = platform.posix.__va_list */>) -> platform.android.jobject? /* = kotlinx.cinterop.CPointer<out kotlinx.cinterop.CPointed>? */>>? /* compiled code */
```

And I do not konw how to create `CValue<platform.posix.va_list)` or `va_list`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The function `CallStaticObjectMethodA` and `CallStaticObjectMethodV`  confused me. I thought `CallStaticObjectMethodA` can only pass one params, and `CallStaticObjectMethodV` can pass multiple params. It is wrong. when passing `CPoint<jvalue>`, we can use `CArrayPoint<jvalue>` rather than  `CPoint<jvalue>` .`CArrayPoint` is subclass of `CPoint`. As I do, I can pass multiple params to `CallStaticObjectMethodA`:

```
fun getJValues(arguments:Array<out Any?>):CPoint<jvalue>{
    memscope{
        val result = scope.allocArray(arguments.size)
        arguments.mapIndexed{index, it ->
            .....
        }
        return result
    }

}
```